# Query for Records beginning with "The" and move "The" the end of a string and join with a comma in Rails Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, postgresql

I have a data set that I'm trying to sort alphabetically.   A lot of records have a "the" at the beginning.  I'd like to query for records with a "The" (ie.  The Irish Bar) and move the "The" to the end of the string and join with a comma (ie, "Irish Bar").

I feel like this should be a Regular Expression to query and then updating.  It seems a bit hacky, there must be an elegant solution as it's not an uncommon requirement.

```
regexp = \w+[The]  (?????)
records = Record.where("title LIKE ?", regexp)

records.each do |record|
  record.title = "title witthou the the + ", The"
  record.save
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to find records beginning with "the" (edited for case-insensitive):

```
records = Record.where("lower(title) LIKE :prefix", prefix: "#{the}%")
```

Then use sub to replace the "the", then update the records:

```
records.each do |r|
  r.title = r.title.sub(/the/i, "")
  r.title = "#{r.title}, The"
  r.save
end
```